# How to dispose of a large full length mirror?

Tags: mirror

I have this mirror that I am replacing. This mirror was extremely heavy and fell off the wall one time and the frame is broken. The mirror/glass part is all in good shape. The edges are just sharp and it's heavy so I don't know how to dispose of it. Or where I can take it.

Comment: Where are you? Every country, often state or county or city, has different rules and options. Where I am, you can schedule a special trash pickup or take it to the Solid Waste Transfer Station (aka "the dump"). Some places have warehouses where people can drop off items like this for others to reuse. It varies a **lot**. Unless you are in Montgomery County, MD, my answers won't help you.

Comment: Take it to recycling - wear gloves.

Answer (score 3):

Craigslist (or equivalent) "free mirror, broken frame" with pictures. Or a low price, which sometimes works better than free even without the aspect below...

or

Set beside the street, sign "free" (if that does not work, set a price and hope someone steals it now that it has value, or be pleasantly surprised if someone actually pays the price. Or just start there.)

Comment: "free" on the curb works quite well in most places. Doesn't work if you're "in the middle of nowhere" (nobody passing by to take it) and I'm sure there are some places where doing that would violate homeowners association rules or other craziness. But I've gotten rid of a **lot** of old computers (with hard drives removed) that way.

Comment: A "free" tall mirror with sharp edges that could fall and become a pile of knives is not going to get you many friends among your neighbours if you leave it in the street, and maybe law enforcement would have something to say.

Comment: Items can sit for days with "Free" on them in my neighborhood, but when I change the sign to $20 or some insignificant price, they're gone in minutes.

Comment: I am going to agree - putting this on the street is about as dumb as possible.   You could get sued if someone got hurt.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to trash it, the easiest way is to break it up small enough to fit in a trash can. Lay it down and cover the front with packing tape, then go at it with a hammer or crowbar (wear gloves, heavy jeans, closed toed shoes, safety glasses, and ideally a hoodie with a high neck). Take it slow, break it and put into a trash can. The can will be HEAVY by the end, so you might need a couple.

Comment: UK official recycling advice: "Broken non-packaging glass which isn’t recyclable like drinking glasses, mirrors and Pyrex but also broken crockery should securely wrapped before presenting them for collection as general waste."